# Jenkins retrieve details of last successful build

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I have jenkins pipeline (Jenkinsfile) for build process, which setup build version number for each build once its successful. Now want to retrieve details like `currentBuild.displayName` of previous successful build in jenkinsfile and increment current builds build number.

I don't want to use Jenkins build number, because failed build numbers are wasted if I use Jenkins Build number.

Can get this with groovy `def buildName = Jenkins.instance.getItem('Gateway').lastSuccessfulBuild.displayName`

But how can I run it in `Jenkinsfile` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use it in `script` block:

```
steps {
    script{
        def lastSuccessBuildName = Jenkins.instance.getItem(env.JOB_NAME).lastSuccessfulBuild.displayName
        echo "Last Success Build Name: ${lastSuccessBuildName}"
    }
}
```